# Compile with GCC and relocate the linked libraries

Tags: gcc, linker

I have my `soft.c` and I compile it successfully and link it against `/usr/lib/myLib.so`.

Everything it's ok except for the fact that it's not what I'm looking for, i would like to manage the final path considered for the linking, in other words i want GCC to consider the library `/usr/lib/myLib.so` but I also want the final linking to be a relative path, kinda like `../myLib.so`.

The usual scenario is

`./soft` linked to -> `/usr/lib/myLib.so`

I want

`./soft` linked to -> `../myLib.so`

Obiviously I also need GCC to manage any cross referenced library, for example if `/usr/lib/myLib.so` is linked to other libs i want all the libraries involved to be relocated in the relative path so `../myLib.so` can fully work from a relative path .

How to achieve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include run-time search path information in the binaries, using the `-rpath` option to the linker (passed to gcc as `-Wl,-rpath,`.

Note that this is generally frowned upon by distribution maintainers, as there should be a single system-wide library search path so conflicts are caught early.

Comment: close to the solution but it's not really what i want. this adds 1 more search dir to the linker, I want my executable linked only to my relative, without including any other option, i prefer to miss a library from the relative path rather than having a pool of directories where my executable can be linked to and not knowing for sure what library will be used. With -rpath the system wide libs are still in use.